# Calling Skype for business account from normal skype app

Tags: android, skype, skype-for-business

I need to make a call to skype for business account through the normal skype app using the intent in android.

I have tried a lot of options but no one works.

Option #1:

```
val skype = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW")
skype.data = Uri.parse("skype:$skypeID?call")
startActivity(skype)
```

Option #2:

```
val skype = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW")
skype.data = Uri.parse("ms-sfb://call?id=$skypeID")
skype.component = ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main")
        skype.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(skype)
```

both options are not working for that.

Please if there is anyone have the same issue before, I need your help.

Thanks,